# Android - Same JSON parsing class for different web services

Tags: android, json, performance, listview, json-api

I have made a JSONParse class for parsing JSON response. I have to call 3 web services. But I want to use only that SINGLE class for parsing JSON response for all 3 web services. All 3 web services has different keys and values. What I have done is like below..

**MainActivity.java**

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemClickListener {

    // Anything Else Goes Here
    private ArrayList<ModelCourse> ArrayListModelCourses;

    // Variables
    private String url = "stream.php";
    private String career_path = "";

    // Widgets
    private ListView lv;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        init();
    }

    private void init() {
        initialisation();
        find_view_by_id();
        clickListners();
        fetchData();
    }

    private void initialisation() {
        ArrayListModelCourses = new ArrayList<>();
    }

    private void find_view_by_id() {
        lv = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.list_view);
    }

    private void clickListners() {
        lv.setOnItemClickListener(this);
    }

    private void fetchData() {
        StringRequest stringReq = new StringRequest(Request.Method.POST, Constants.base_url + url, new Response.Listener<String>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(String response) {
                try {
                    JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(response);
                    if (jo.has("success")) {
                        JsonParse jsonParse = new JsonParse(response);
                        ArrayListModelCourses = jsonParse.parseJson();
                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error msg from server!!", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    }
                } catch (JSONException e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
                CustomAdapter ca = new CustomAdapter(getApplicationContext(), ArrayListModelCourses);
                lv.setAdapter(ca);
            }
        }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error:" + error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }
        }) {
            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                params.put("user_id", "51");
                return params;
            }
        };
        RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(this);
        queue.add(stringReq);
    }


    @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> adapterView, View view, int position, long id) {
        String stream_name = ArrayListModelCourses.get(position).getmCourse_name();
        String stream_id = ArrayListModelCourses.get(position).getmCourse_id();

        career_path += stream_name + ", ";
        fetchData();
    }
}
```

**JsonParse.java - The single class that I want to use for 3 web services.**

```
    public class JsonParse {

    // Anything Else Goes Here
    ArrayList<ModelCourse> modelCourses = new ArrayList<>();

    // Variables
    public static final String KEY_ARRAY = "stream_name";
    public static final String KEY_ID = "stream_id";
    public static final String KEY_NAME = "stream_name";

    private String mJsonRes;

    public JsonParse(String jsonRes) {
        this.mJsonRes = jsonRes;
    }

    public ArrayList<ModelCourse> parseJson() throws JSONException {

        JSONObject jo = new JSONObject(mJsonRes);
        JSONArray ja = jo.getJSONArray(KEY_ARRAY);

        for (int i = 0; i < ja.length(); i++) {
            ModelCourse modelCourseObj = new ModelCourse();
            JSONObject object = ja.getJSONObject(i);
            modelCourseObj.mCourse_id = object.getString(KEY_ID);
            modelCourseObj.mCourse_name = object.getString(KEY_NAME);
            modelCourses.add(modelCourseObj);
        }
        return modelCourses;
    }
}
```

Thanks in advance.

Comment: What went wrong? Any errors?

Comment: is it working or not ? logcat please

Comment: It is working for single web service. But I can not find LOGIC for consuming 3 different web services with single class.@DäñishShärmà
@ibtehaz

Comment: Why not just use a library like GSON?

Comment: Ya, I know but some reason I have to use VOLLEY. @Ben

Comment: You have three webservices, so you have to set up an identifier of some sorts which KEY-VALUE pairs you're going to use. However, the best practice is NOT to use one class. Instead, use multiple class according to your need as your need and servers configuration may change! 

BEST PRACTICE: Implement your JSONPerse class from another class. In that way, your class name same bt your will get different config based which class u are in and/or which API you want to parse....

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Can you please elaborate? @ibtehaz

Answer (score 0):

Use can use Gson for mapping json data to objects.

Create models classes for your json data. (use link http://www.jsonschema2pojo.org/)

Now in your MainActivity onResponse() method pass the string response to JsonParse class.

In JsonParse class parse your json data

```
  Gson gson = new Gson();
  gson.fromJson(jsonString, JsonModelRootClassName.class);
```

You can create one method to get "JsonModelRootClassName" based on your web services call.

Comment: Can you give some link which have example of Gson. @sanjeet kumar Singh

Comment: you can refer to https://www.javacodegeeks.com/2011/01/android-json-parsing-gson-tutorial.html